# python 3 possible magic methods

Tags: python, python-3.x

Which of these magic methods could be realised in my own class?
1) `__new__`
2) `__hash__`
3) `__float__`
4) `__list__`
5) `__set__`

I answered all except 4), but the testing system talks I am not right. What is your version?

Comment: What do you mean by "Could be realized"? You're correct that all of them but `__list__` are supported special methods, though it would be a *very* rare class that used both `__float__` and `__set__` (`__set__` is part of the descriptor protocol, and a descriptor that can be coerced to `float` is a strange idea).

Comment: Maybe you are right, I should remove `__set__` from my answer. But the question sounds strange, I agreed, it's about a bad test.